# jQuery load more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have this great little bit of code that works really well with Wordpress. It basically adds a load more button to a custom loop and when clicked adds the next lot of posts underneath.

The problem I have is with this line of code taken from the below snippett: `error: function() { jQuery('button.load-more').attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('No More Posts') } // Disable the button and change its contents when there are no more posts`

Basically when there are no more posts, the button doesn't get disabled as instructed. Can somebody help me fix? Here's the JS in full:

```
var page = 1;

loadMore = function () {
    page++ //Increments the page number in the request
    $.ajax({
        url: './page/' + page,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#wait').show().parent().find('button.load-more').hide();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#wait').hide().parent().find('button.load-more').show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var $data = $(data).find('article');
            // Replace div#the-posts with the name of your post container
            jQuery('#posts .inner').append($data);
        },
        error: function () {
            jQuery('button.load-more').attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('No More Posts')
        } // Disable the button and change its contents when there arew no more posts

    }); // End Ajax
}; // End loadMore

jQuery('button.load-more').on('click', loadMore);
```

Comment: To disable element use .prop instead of .attr.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks but that doesn't fix the issue

Comment: The script relies on the request returning a 404 when it hits a page number that doesn't exist. Apparently the server doesn't do that.

Comment: You shouldn't be using text on a button. Use `.attr('val', 'valueyouwant')`. unless button isn't an `input`

Comment: @Juhana So what are you saying? I'm testing locally at the moment. If I put it on a live server it might work?

Comment: Look in the browser dev tools's network tab. Does the server return a 404 response when it tries to load a page that doesn't exist?

Comment: @JeffShaver `<button>` isn't an `<input>`. `.text()` is fine.

Comment: @Juhana Well this is a screenshot of what I see: http://cl.ly/image/3C243q1z3517 2 is loads up the last remaining post. 3 is what happens when I click the button and nothing happens. Doesn't return 404. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error function is only called when the server returns some kind of error status code, which does not seem to happen.

My guess is that you need to check the response. The following could work:

```
    success: function (data) {
        var $data = $(data).find('article');
        if ($data.length > 0) {  
          // Replace div#the-posts with the name of your post container
          jQuery('#posts .inner').append($data);
        }
        else {
          jQuery('button.load-more').attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('No More Posts');
        }
    },
```

But it's only a guess, since I don't know how the reponse looks like.

Comment: Just the ticket. I was playing around with tracking the response with an IF statement but I got it all wrong. I'm such a noob!